# C# ASP.NET equivalent of PHP bracket scope?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

In PHP you can do the following:

```
<?php if($x == 1) { ?>
    // Display HTML here
<?php } else { ?>
    // Display alternate HTML here
<?php } ?>
```

There does not appear to be an obvious equivalent in ASP.NET using C#. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `.aspx` pages

```
<% if (something) { %>
    <!-- html -->
<% } else { %>
    <!-- html -->
<% } %>
```

If you are using Razor view engine (`.cshtml`)

```
@if (something)
{
    <!-- html -->
}
else
{
    <!-- html -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is. It is called [Embedded Code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <% for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) %>
       <% { Response.Write("<br>" + i.ToString()); }%>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) you can turn the code/as-is block "problem" around.

E.g.

```
@{
    var foo = 2.99;
    if( 0==foo )
    {
        <p>zero</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>not zero</p>
    }
}
```

or

```
@for( var i=0; i<9; i++ )
{
    <p># @i</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I am actually using a solution similar to this. What I am finding is that the "not zero" code is loading for a brief moment before being hidden and replaced by the "zero" block. Do you know a way of stopping this?